# Accessing foreign key from a one to many relationship using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 with Entity Framework code first.

I have the following models:

```
public class Member {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Initial")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the last initial of your last name.")]
    [MaxLength(1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your city.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
}

public class Favorite {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

My code is receiving a list of search terms `List<string> searchTerms` from the front end. I need to search the values of every members' favorites for every search term.

I'm working the following LINQ statement:

```
return db.Favorites.Where(f => searchTerms.Any(s => f.Value.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

My issue is this will return a `List<Favorite>` which is great but what I really need is the ID of the member associated in the database. This unfortunately is not an option I can pick in LINQ

```
return db.Favorites.Where(f => searchTerms.Any(s => f.Value.Contains(s))).Select(f => f.????) .ToList();
```

The ??? only gives me `ID`, `Type`, `Value`. The properties of `Favortie`, however in the database table Entity framework created there's a foreign key column `Member_ID`. But I can't pick that in C#.

So my questions is... how do I? Do I just add a `public virtual int MemberID` in the Favorite class? Will entity framework automatically associate that to the foreign key?

Comment: Why won't you just try adding additional property into `Favorite` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Code First conventions, for adding the foreign key just:

```
public int MemberID { get; set; }
```

If you need the navigation property then

```
public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
```

Check this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) for further information

Comment: `public virtual Member Member { get; set; }` is what I needed thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue in the context of this question I posted  which I still have not resolved: `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d49772c9-c108-4418-b782-e231f60b6ffc/foreign-id-attribute-cannot-be-accessed-in-linq-query-for-an-object-of-a-class-that-has-a-list-of?forum=csharpgeneral` I added a virtual property of `Folders`, but I still cannot access a `Folder` object's `Folder_Id` foreign key property which was generated by Code First. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the a collection of Members with a filtered children collection.

Example:

```
    return db.Members.Select(member => new
    {
        Member = member,
        Favorites = member.Favorites.Where(f => searchTerms.Any(s => f.Value.Contains(s)))
     }).Where(m => m.Favorites.Any()).ToList();
```

Don't forget the `IEqualityComparer`, or convert to uppercase or lowercase both the search terms and the value

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
   return db.Members.Select(member => new
    {
        Member = member,
        Favorites = member.Favorites.Where(f => searchTerms.Any(s => f.Value.Contains(s)))
     }).Where(m => m.Favorites.Any()).ToList();
```